# Toggle between 2 classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

How can I toggle between two classes in jQuery, while the element does not have either class.

Please note: I want to know if there is a way to do this with the `toggleClass()` method and not by `addClass()`, `removeClass()`. For example:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
    $("#myDiv").toggleClass('red blue') 
})
```

Comment: how can you toggle if it does not exist?

Comment: the above code will add and remove both classes, it will not toggle between them

Comment: `toggleClass("red blue")` will switch both on/off at the same time if neither are on at the start.    If you mean, turn one on then next time turn it off and put the other one on, then no - that makes no sense - you need to have one on to start with.

Comment: Yes but I want it to add the first class, and then toggle back and forth between them. Is this possible without addClass()?

Comment: @madalinivascu not understanding guradio 's comment, I revisited what was being requested and agree with you - removed my comment and added another

Comment: Seems legetimate question imho, not really deserving downvotes...

Comment: "*Yes but I want it to add the first class, and then toggle back and forth between them. Is this possible without addClass()?*" you should add (have added) this to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use function parameter of `toggleClass()` method:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass(function(){
    return $(this).is('.red, .blue') ? 'red blue' : 'red';
  })
});
```

```js
$('#myDiv').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass(function() {
    return $(this).is('.red, .blue') ? 'red blue' : 'red';
  })
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
#myDiv {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  /* Likely future */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  My DIV
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution so far imo!

Comment: best answer i should say :) you just need to know which class to add from the start

Comment: This is the correct answer and what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just use `toggleClass` with more than one class. jQuery will toggle them each by each.

```js
$("div").addClass("red");

setInterval(function() {
    $("div").toggleClass("red blue");
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: but he said that the div doesnt have any class onload.

Comment: And? Whats the problem? Thats the sense of `toggle`, if the class is not available it will be added. My code is just an example. @callback

Comment: Yea, but I'm realizing it is impossible. I wanted it to toggle between the two classes, without having an initial class. I guess it's not possible with toggle class alone.

Comment: @eisbehr: Ah, sorry. I didn't see any text saying you (like me) had happily violated the requirement, and missed that line of code. (I also took it that this was meant to wait for the first click before adding either class.)